# mojolicious - barewords - mojocast 2

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

Following along with mojocasts episode 2 to learn mojolicious.

I have got the example in

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/:fname/:lname' => sub {
    shift->render('hello');
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ hello.html.ep
<!doctype html><html>
    <head><title>Placeholders</title></head>
    <body><i>Hello <%= fname %> <%= $lname %></li></body>
</html>
```

However when I go to the address `http://127.0.0.1:3000/sayth/renshaw` I get this error from the server.

```
[Fri Apr 25 15:59:05 2014] [error] Bareword "fname" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at template hello.html.ep from DATA section line 3, <DATA> line 17.
1: <!doctype html><html>
2:     <head><title>Placeholders</title></head>
3:     <body><i>Hello <%= fname %> <%= $lname %></li></body>
4: </html>
```

I don't believe I have specified strict subs, how do I fix this?

Edit: I am running the latest version installed by curl with perl 5.16.3 installed.

Comment: You need a `$` in front of `fname` in your template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojolicious enables `use strict;` by default.  Be thankful  :)

The error is the same as you would get in perl code:

```
Bareword "fname" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at template hello.html.ep
```

Basically, you're just missing a dollar sign before `fname`:

```
@@ hello.html.ep
<!doctype html><html>
    <head><title>Placeholders</title></head>
    <body><i>Hello <%= $fname %> <%= $lname %></li></body>
</html>
```

Or you can use this format as well:

```
@@ hello.html.ep
<!doctype html><html>
    <head><title>Placeholders</title></head>
    <body><i>Hello <%= param('fname') %> <%= param('lname') %></li></body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that just would be because mojolicous has updated since screencasts.